# Is there any workaround to the Mongo _id field type limitation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I am using Meteor with a pre-existing database which uses custom objects in the `_id` field. I have defined the structure with Meteor like this:

```
_id: {
    type: Object,
    label: "ID"
},

"_id.templateId" : {
    type: String,
    label: "Template ID",
    optional: false
},

"_id.locale": {
    type: String,
    optional: false
},
```

However, when I try to use the collection, I get an error stating that "Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids."

Is there a workaround which would allow me to use this collection in Meteor without having to change the existing database?

Comment: The error says "Error: Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids", that should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: As for the issue I think it will be extremely hard to circumvent this measure of Meteor, which relies heavily on the `_id` being a `String` or an `ObjectId`. You may instead want to migrate your entire database to use `yourProductId` to place the information you want, and then if needed index the new Mongo database with `_ensureIndex`.

Comment: @Marco Did you find the solution? I also stuck in the same issue.

Comment: @HarishKommuri sorry but at the moment i didn't find a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an object literal as an id composition, but Meteor only supports `String` and `ObjecID` but `String` is preferable because almost every package that rely on id information assume strings.

Also, the built in accounts system cannot work with anything other than simple string id's.